# High pass filter for use in amplifier circuit

Tags: amplifier, bjt, high-frequency, amplitude-modulation, high-pass-filter

I've designed an amplifier for a small ac signal (amplitude of around 5mV, frequency 252kHz) with a BJT (2N2222.)

The BJT is set up in a common emitter amplifier configuration, with the biasing resistors set up to provide a constant 0.7Vdc to the base.

I used blocking capacitors C2 and C4 to remove the dc bias by acting as a high pass filter.

However, even though I designed the circuit to have a voltage gain of 100, with cut off frequency of around 200kHz, I found my ac input signal was still being attenuated.

By changing the cut off frequency to 20Hz, I achieved a gain of close to 100. However, even by changing the cut off freq to 100kHz, my output signal is still attenuated.

Why is this?

[image]

Comment: What considerations have you given to the [Miller effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_effect)? The 2N2222 BJT model in LTspice has, by default, CJC=8 pF (and CJE=25 pF.) Your gain is 100 and it looks like you are running about 9-10 mA for the quiescent collector current, at a guess. Since you designed this, perhaps you could discuss the details here, including how you treated the BJT parasitics in your analysis and set the values for your capacitors in the circuit. Finally, did you actually build this? Or are you discussing the attenuation that LTspice is showing you in simulation?

Comment: Hi, I didn't give any consideration to the miller effect, I wasn't aware of its existence (only in second year elec eng). You'd be correct for the gain and collector current. To design it, I followed this guide: http://www.hunter.cuny.edu/physics/courses/physics222/repository/files/pdf/ElectronicsLab15.pdf - I didn't take into account the parasitics, and designed it to have a collector current of 10mA and hfe of 150. I've been playing around with the capacitor values and at the moment have settled on a cut off freq of 100Hz, as this doesn't seem to attenuate my output. I haven't built this,

Comment: I'm discussing the attenuation LTspice shows in the simulation. Thanks.

Comment: When you get anywhere above perhaps \$100\:\text{kHz}\$ with standard small signal BJTs, you have to start worrying about stuff. Also, with high collector currents you run into other issues, as well. (Current crowding, ohmic parasitics...) A design should also take into account thermal effects and variations in parts (parts from a single BJT type might vary \$\pm 30\:\text{mV}\$ in their \$V_\text{BE}\$ (or more) and might vary over \$\beta\$, too. Given your desire for high gain which is pushing common BJT limits, you may find difficulty and instead want to split into two stages.

Comment: Is your signal really a \$50\:\Omega\$ source? Because, if so, common base is probably the way to go. If not, what is the source impedance?

Comment: Hi, so my 10mA collector current was based off this data sheet [http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/296640.pdf], with a Vce of 10V so that I could achieve a higher gain. I edited my post to include the design I'm using now, with 2 BJTs. Yes, my input signal is taken off a 50ohm resistor as i've a bandpass filter before the amplifier which uses the resistor as the output. However in the new schematic it's now 10 ohms. I have run into further problems in that my theoretical gain is way larger than the gain I'm getting after my 2 BJTs. I designed the circuit to have a total gain of 2500, 50*50

Comment: My actual gain is around 1000. I'm not entirely sure why to be honest.

Comment: What gain do you ***really*** want? Is this about just learning to design CE amplifier stages and you don't care about the gain at all? Or is it okay to consider common base designs? Is the signal source impedance supposed to be 50 Ohms, 10 Ohms, 1000 Ohms, or does that matter??? I'm confused about what your ***real goals*** are, here. Chapters written for each of CE, CC and CB arrangements, complete with design rules, etc? Or is there something practical. If this is just education, then you need to PICK SOMETHING and stick with it. Slippery specs make teaching very hard.

Comment: Ok, so this amplifier is for an AM radio. I chose common emitter because we'd covered it to some extent in lectures- however this only covered analyzing a CE amp, not actually designing one. 10 ohms was chosen based on our RLC bandpass filter design, allowing a very high Q factor. The goal of this circuit was to take the filtered output from the bandpass filter @ 252kHz and amplify it to around 1 - 2 V amplitude so that it could be demodulated. I could use an OP amp, however 2N2222s are significantly cheaper which has to factor into our design. I also struggled to find a suitable op amp to

Comment: use in this amplifier due to the high frequency. I also enjoyed the challenge...

Comment: Does your RLC bandpass filter truly have an output impedance (source to the amplifier) of 10 Ohms??? That's pretty stiff. I like it, if true. And if true, you should definitely use CB, not CE. And yes, I paid 0.0032 USD for each 2N2222A I get, so they are very cheap. But I expect you will be paying a LOT MORE for the resistors. They will dissipate anywhere near 10 mA quiescent (assuming you can make that much current work -- in CB, you can't.) Also, is your voltage rail 20 V? 10 V? Or what, exactly?

Comment: The voltage input is taken off the node of the 10ohm resistor in the bandpass filter if that's what you mean

Comment: I suppose you'll need to show the RLC bandpass filter and what precedes it. I'm having a hard time believing an output impedance that low and I'm no longer trusting your estimates since they've varied moment to moment and you've admitted this is 2nd yr. A CB design would likely be best if you are right but again ***only*** if you can actually drive the CB design. We could just assume things, I suppose. The worst that happens is that it doesn't work because the assumptions were wrong. Also, the AC gain will heavily depend on your source impedance.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So your source impedance is about \$8.9-0.8\,j\$ or in other words about \$9\:\Omega\$ with about \$-5^\circ\$ of phase shift. CB would seem appropriate. (I just grounded the voltage source and "looked inward" to get that.)

Comment: I edited my original post to show the full circuit. The ac voltage source and 50 ohm resistor is a model of a radio antenna we're given in the brief. 20Vdc source as I wanted to keep the base at 0.7V, but also because in the document I linked earlier, they stated that Vs/3 < Vce < Vs/2 as a general rule of thumb. By choosing Vs = 20V, it'd allow me to get Vce = 10V, allowing me to replicate the conditions in the data sheet I linked earlier for the measured gains.

Comment: Why would common base be more appropriate? I suppose I'd be more weary of trying to implement it as we haven't covered it in lectures. I don't have a whole lot of time to play with before submission so I'm also worried of going down a rabbit hole

Comment: CB provides very high voltage gain and completely negates the Miller effect (which you would like to avoid.) It's not hard and designing one looks almost like designing a CE stage. Not much of a rabbit hole, really. I think the CE stages (two) is actually "harder" and more of a rabbit hole. But I take your point about it not being covered. I'll toss one up in just a few minutes. You can look. If you don't like it, oh well.

Comment: Ok thanks very much for all your help

Comment: Added. Hopefully, it makes some sense. There are some problems I probably should spend more time describing (you don't really know your source impedance and it impacts the gain -- you could add some series resistance to help make it more knowable, but then you'd definitely have to lower your quiescent current choice.) Added power supply bypassing. Etc. But it's a start. (I had to use my maximum typing speed and put my brain on cruise control to get it written that fast. If I missed something, it may come to me later.)

Comment: That looks good, thank you!

Comment: If it's an answer for you, feel free to mark it as such. If not, or you want to see answers more squarely along the lines of a CE amplifier arrangement, then just leave it be for others. Your call. And thanks for clarifying every question I asked. It was a productive exchange and I thank you for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just say (for now) that your source impedance is \$R_\text{S}=9\:\Omega\$. (Or any other value you like, I suppose.) Your driving circuit appears to have very low output impedance. So a common base voltage amplifier design is indicated here, I think.

Let's design one.

Both the 2N2222A and the 2N3904 do fine with \$I_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}=10\:\text{mA}\$. So let's keep that choice you made for now. The basic layout for the common base design is the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f77z6n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It looks a lot like a common-emitter design, and you can DC-bias it using a very similar approach, but the operation is different. The common-base design takes the capacitor normally used to accept a signal and apply it to the base of a common-emitter and grounds it (or ties it to \$V_\text{CC}\$.) With a large enough value for \$C_1\$, \$Q_1\$'s base is effectively tied to ground from an AC perspective. Now, the input signal is moved from the base to the emitter, via the usual DC-blocking capacitor, and the output signal is taken from the collector (as it would also have been with a common-emitter design.)

Summarizing, in changing from a common-emitter design to a common base design, the input signal is moved from the base to the emitter, the base is then AC-grounded, and the output signal is taken from the collector, same as before. You get a lot of potential voltage gain (which you apparently want) but you have to have a signal source capable of driving the emitter (which you apparently have.) And finally, your output signal is in-phase (instead of opposite-phase) and that helps to eliminate the [Miller effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_effect) I'd mentioned elsewhere in comments, earlier. (The AC-grounded base, in effect, protects the collector signal from feeding back to the emitter input.) This improves the frequency response (which I think you want.) It's not uncommon to see RF amplifier stages using common-base (though they also use RF BJTs, too.)

Down to the design:

1. \$A_{vo}\ge 100\$ and assuming \$V_{\text{IN}_\text{PEAK}}\approx 5\:\text{mV}\$ gives \$V_{\text{OUT}_\text{PEAK}}\ge 500\:\text{mV}\$. This output swings only over a full range of \$V_{\text{OUT}_\text{PP}}\ge 1\:\text{V}\$.
2. In a common-base design, \$A_{vo}=\frac{R_\text{C}}{R_\text{S}+r_e}\$. Since \$R_\text{S}\approx 9\:\Omega\$ and since \$r_e\$ is set by your choice of quiescent current, this means \$R_\text{C}=100\cdot\left(9\:\Omega+\frac{V_T}{10\:\text{mA}}\right)\approx 1.2\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and it will quiescently drop \$12\:\text{V}\$ resulting in \$V_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}=8\:\text{V}\$.
3. I like to see \$V_\text{CE}\ge 4\:\text{V}\$ at all times, so I'll set \$V_{\text{E}_\text{Q}}=3.5\:\text{V}\$. This means that \$R_\text{E}\approx \frac{3.5\:\text{V}}{10\:\text{mA}}=350\:\Omega\$. Call it the nearby standard value of \$R_\text{E}=390\:\Omega\$ and therefore \$V_{\text{E}_\text{Q}}=3.9\:\text{V}\$.
4. The base resistor divider pair needs to supply the base current for \$Q_1\$ and it should maintain it's divider voltage reasonably well. You could nickel-and-dime exactly how much, but a rule that works pretty well is to use a divider current (don't confuse this with base current) of about \$\frac1{10}\$th the quiescent collector current. (Same as with common CE design thoughts for biasing.) This means about \$1\:\text{mA}\$ or so. The guaranteed minimum \$\beta\$ for both the 2N2222 and the 2N3904 when operating around \$10\:\text{mA}\$ is \$\beta=100\$. So \$R_2=\frac{3.9\:\text{V}+700\:\text{mV}}{1\:\text{mA}}=4.6\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_1=\frac{20\:\text{V}-3.9\:\text{V}-700\:\text{mV}}{1\:\text{mA}+100\:\mu\text{A}}=14\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Call them \$R_2=4.7\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_1=15\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNJesA.png)</sup>

Try using that circuit in your simulation with your input source and see how it flies. You can increase \$R_\text{C}\$ a little to get more gain. But it will press the BJT more towards saturation, so be careful about just randomly changing one resistor to get more gain. (You might be able to press \$R_\text{C}=1.5\:\text{k}\Omega\$ in the above -- but that's squeezing into saturation and there's no more than that without re-calculating things. There's a process above and you can follow it if you really want more gain.)

If I made this, I'd use dead-bug construction. No solderless breadboard.

Keep in mind that there is a lot here that is NOT under managament. \$r_e\$ is significant, varies with temperature, and is close to the value of your assumed source impedance. I just threw in capacitor values with barely any thought at all, so feel free to adjust them. But it sounds as though you aren't looking for an exact gain. Just something in the ballpark of where you need it. You can always increase the gain by increasing \$R_\text{C}\$ but then you may need to reduce \$I_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}\$ so that the voltage drop across it is back within the right ballpark. Doing so will increase \$r_e\$ and therefore a temperature dependent bit of the voltage gain will be even more temperature dependent. But maybe that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

The input impedance is dominated by Beta * (reac + Re), paralleled by the base biasing.

Zin = 100 * (26 ohm/Ie_ma + 5)

Zin = 100 * (26 ohm / (5v/500 ohm) + 5 ohm)

Zin = 100 * (26/10mA + 5)

Zin = 100 * (2.6 + 5) = 100 * 7.6 = only 760 ohms.

..........................................

Now for the gain. Gain is: Rcollector (all resistors/impedances on Collector, in **parallel**) divided by the **series** sum of all impedances in the emitter path including Z(C3) and "reac" and the 5 ohms.
Know that reac is 1/gm, = 26 ohms/Iemitter_milliAmps.

At the Fcarrier, Z(C3) must be low compared to the 5 ohm resistor.

1uF at 1MHz is =j0.159 ohms.

1uF at 0.1MHz is -j1.59 ohms.

Make C3 be 1uF.

................................................

Make C2 and C4 also 1uF.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your notation at the start, could you clarify further please?

Comment: The slope of the diode (the base-emitter diode) is 0.026/Idiode_amps. The 0.026 is kt/q in the diode, and we use this value in computing transconductance (GM); the inverse of GM is the dV/dI, or ohms, of the diode. That diode, plus your 5 ohms, scaled up by BETA, is the Rin of the transistor base.

Comment: \$r_{Eac}\$ is the base emitter AC incremental resistance at stated bias current