# Common base bias divider resistances

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, resistors, common-base

I have been trying to grok the common base amplifier, and put together a few examples, but there is something that I do not get at all.  I have the setup below.  Things are working more or less as expected, but I measured the resistance of the bias divider, and even though I have a \$50k\$ and a \$100k\$ resistor, I measure \$\sim 33k\$ across both parts of the bias divider.  Why does this happen?

I suspect that \$R_2\$, \$R_4\$, and the BE junction make up one part of a divider somehow and \$R_1\$, \$R_3\$, and the BC junction make up the other.  Am I on the right track?  How can I calculate these results reliably?

I should mention (since it's probably nearing finals time for students) that I am not a student.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2bVY7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You are going to have a lot of trouble if you don't follow why the \$50\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor and the \$100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistors set between two power rails make up \$50\:\text{k}\Omega\mid\mid 100\:\text{k}\Omega\approx 33.3\:\text{k}\Omega\$. That's a basic element you need to follow right away. Next is that the common base arrangement should, if oriented well for reading, look a lot like a CE arrangement except that the signal is removed from the input capacitor with that end of the capacitor then grounded, instead.

Comment: Evidently it's been a long day.  Clearly 50k || 100k = 33k.  No clue what I was thinking there.

Comment: So, are you interested how the common base functions? You could examine [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/431189/38098) I wrote, earlier. I've oriented the schematic better, so it might make more sense.

Comment: Well, yes. But here I thought something had gone mysteriously wrong because I was dumb and not thinking of the equiv value of the resistance in the divider for some reason.  It's like if I had forgot how to add numbers while learning how to solve PDEs...

Comment: Well, read the above link I provided and see if it helps.

Comment: @jonk Thanks, that looks very helpful!  My hope was to figure out how to design a common base amplifier instead of just analyze an existing one - and it looks like that post does just that.  Not sure why, but I can't find a book that details design of common base.

Comment: Hopefully, it helps a bit. Feel free to ask questions there, too. Or just ask a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBIock.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I'll be accepting this to close the question.  I know how dividers work, for some reason (lack of sleep?) I didn't recognize that the value should be 33k here... Sorry for the dumb question